# Не могу добавить ярлычок на панель быстрого запуска

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

Привет. Не получается добавить тулзу, которая лежит в папке, в хомяке. Тулза легко запускается так:

```
cd ~/programs/Gogland-*/bin/ && ./gogland.sh
```

Когда я её запустил, то на панели быстрого запуска появляется ярлычок:

[image: Панель быстрого запуска]
[image: Ярлычок]

Но закрепляться он не хочет почему-то. Хелп. Подскажите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Запускаете *GoLang*
2. Идете `Tools -> Generate Desktop Entry`
3. Закрываете *GoLang*
4. В терминале стартуем *Nautilus* от рута (`sudo nautilus`)
5. Заходим в `/usr/share/applications`
6. Перетаскиваем мышкой созданную выше иконку для GoLang на Launcher

Comment: Вполне хватает Идете Tools -> Generate Desktop Entry. Спасибо